# Accumulator and while loops

Tags: c++

```
while(true) {
  infile >> studentCode >> test1 >> test2 >> lab >> finalExam;

  finalG = finalGrade(test1, test2, lab, finalExam);
  gradeSum = gradeSum + finalG;
  letterG = letterGrade(finalG);
  gradePrinter();       // Prints grades to outfile.

  if (infile.eof())
    break;
}
```

In my while loop, the variable finalG does not add to gradeSum at the end of every loop. (gradeSum is initialized to 0 before the while loop). Instead, the value of gradeSum stays at zero and just adds whatever the last number the function finalGrade(test1, test2, lab, finalExam) outputs. For example, if the following numbers are outputted by function:

10

15

30

35

40

The  gradeSum will return 40 + 0, which just gives me 40 rather than the sum of the numbers. How can I fix this?

Comment: are all the variables allocated outside of the `while` loop?

Comment: Are you sure you are returning the right variable?  Please post an [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Your use of the `while` loop is faulty. You end up processing the grades one more time than is valid.

Let's say you have two lines in your file:

```
101 18 20 15 48
102 19 20 14 50
```

After the second line is read, `infile.eof()` is `false`. Hence, you continue reading. Reading does not succeed. Yet you process those numbers. You will probably end up processing the last line twice.

**A solution**

Simplify the `while` loop by using:

```
while ( infile >> studentCode >> test1 >> test2 >> lab >> finalExam )
{
  finalG = finalGrade(test1, test2, lab, finalExam);
  gradeSum = gradeSum + finalG;
  letterG = letterGrade(finalG);
  gradePrinter();
}
```

**Disclaimer:** This won't fix other logic errors in your code.

Comment: You may be right, but this does not explain why he gets the wrong sum in the end. If the last line was processed twice,the sum should be much larger but not just 40

Comment: @tobi303, you are right. Hence the disclaimer in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even notice the last line was repeated.